# Im doing a migration from prestashop 1.6 to 1.7 and I have a problem with a module thats been bought Advanced Pack 5

Tags: php, migration, prestashop, hook, prestashop-1.7

I enabled debug mode and there is no problem so far  [this is how the backend should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfuTZ.png)

[And here is mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRdWa.png)

As you can see mine lacks the pack configuration option and the hook responsible for it is called so I dont know where the problem is

```
public function hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra($params)
```

..........................................

```
return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/hook/admin-product-tab-new-pack.tpl');
```

Advanced Pack 5 module was working fine in 1.6 but when I installed it on 1.7 it doesnt seem to work what do I need change in the code.
I am stuck and dont know what to do please help with any advice thank you

Comment: Have you checked if there is an update for the software?

Comment: Disable the module to see if you can continue with the migration or run into other obstacles. Contact the vendor of _Advanced Pack 5_ for your support options.

Comment: @NigelRen Yes there is an update for the module but I dont have access to the account that bought it, I thought maybe there is something to change in the code

Comment: Probably best to try and contact them and explain what has happened. They might help, but that is up to them.

Answer (score 1):

Logic of `hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra` has been changed in 1.7. Hook doesn't create a separate tab for every module. It displays info in module options under the "Modules" tab. If you want to change/fix it you should contact your module developer.

You can read about it and all the other changes [HERE](https://build.prestashop.com/news/module-development-changes-in-17/)